# Detect click on .draggable() element for which the start event was not fired

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

[This documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#events) shows that the "start" event for a `.draggable()` element is not fired if a user clicks on it, but doesn't move the mouse before releasing the click.

How can I detect if the user has clicked on the element without moving the mouse?

I want this is to *overload* the element. If the user drags the element, fine. Otherwise, do something else.

Comment: Have you tried using JQuery to attach a click event to the target? http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Actually, it only works when you _first_ define `.draggable()`, and _then_ `.click()`. The other way round fails. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgraded comment to answer:
Have you tried using JQuery to attach a click event to the target? api.jquery.com/click